# GoogleSignIn using Firebase application open url options not called

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, gmail, google-signin

I am trying to integrate google sign in using firebase. I have successfully displayed the google sign in button on the view. But as soon as I tap on it, SafariViewController opens up trying to open Google sign in in i,t but it abruptly closes and comes back to the previous view controller.

infact this method is also not being called.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool

{

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let sourceApplication: String? = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String


            return  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,                                                                                                                                                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                                                                                                                                                  annotation: [:])

    }


  return true

}

public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    return   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)


}
```